# Can Ajax be used to manipulate client-side files?

Tags: ajax

Can Ajax be used to manipulate client-side files? If so, how?

Comment: what you want? do you want to upload file?

Comment: just check 
http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_ajax_example__asynchronous_file_upload.xml

Comment: Are you asking if you can use AJAX to trigger an event to the server so that a file is fetched and copied to the local/client machine ?

Comment: AJAX is a mechanism for making remote requests, nothing else.

Comment: it was a Q I faced in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

No, ajax (=javascript) is sandboxed, it cannot access anything on the computer where the browser is running except the browser. Imagine what would happen if you would surf on the web and suddenly the file `C:\boot.ini` is deleted :/

Comment: @zneak: the irritating part is that people don't explain their downvotes.

Comment: I down-voted it for not being useful. Many efforts are being made to allow browser-based Javascript apps to have closer connections to the client, with Facebook's latest photo-browsing plug-in being a great example. Answering this question with a simple "no", saying "omg what if `C:\boot.ini` were deleted??" isn't helpful -- of course the browser shouldn't be able to take the system down, but that's the browser maker's responsibility, not the Javascript programmer's. Javascript-based plug-in architectures exist for a reason: to answer "yes" to questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do client-side file management if you have special permission from the browser (or other javascript-executing agent) to do so. One good way to get that is to have your script installed as part of a plug-in for Firefox or Chrome, using a toolkit such as [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).

So, the answer is "yes, but ask for permission first!"

Comment: The fact of the matter is that very few users would trust a web site that *wants* to read or write to/from the local file system.  And why should they? Asking for permissions doesn't mean that you will get them and probably 95% of the time you won't.

Comment: That sounds right for the majority of web users, who will pass by anything which requires them to install an extension. However, for a business client, developing a browser extension to allow better desktop integration could be perfectly acceptable.